# Why wont the right item get added?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        minlist<authorinfo> aif = new minlist<authorinfo>();
        aif.Add(new authorinfo("The Count of Monte Cristo","Alexandre", "Dumas", 1844));
        aif.Add(new authorinfo("Rendezvous with Rama", "Arthur", "Clark", 1972));
        aif.Add(new authorinfo("The Three Musketeers", "Alexandre", "Dumas", 1844));
        aif.Add(new authorinfo("2001: A Space Odyssey", "Arthur", "Clark", 1968));
```

4 items,

```
class minlist<T>
{
    T[] storage = new T[3];
    T[] storagereplace = new T[5];
    T[] storagereplace2 = new T[10];
    int spot = 0;

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        if (spot != 3)
        {
            storage[spot] = obj;
            spot++;
            if (spot == 3)
            {
                int spot2 = spot;

                storage.CopyTo(storagereplace, 0);
                storagereplace[spot2] = obj;
                spot2++;
                foreach (T k in storagereplace)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(k);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(spot2);
            }
        }
```

Outcome:

Alexandre, Dumas, The Count of Monte Cristo, 1844

Arthur, Clark, Rendezvous with Rama, 1972

Alexandre, Dumas, The Three Musketeers, 1844

Alexandre, Dumas, The Three Musketeers, 1844

Why does it repeat the last one instead of adding 2001?

Answer (score 3):

because of this:

```
   if (spot != 3)
   {
       storage[spot] = obj;
       spot++;
       if (spot == 3)  
       {
   // etc.
```

think about what this code does if spot is 2. It sets `storage[2] = obj`, then adds 1 to spot, finds out that `spot == 3` and sets `storagereplace[3] = obj`, too.

Just out of curiosity: Why are you implementing your list class that way instead of using the existing [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class?

Still, there are quite a few problems with your class. Like, if spot is larger than 3, `storage[spot] = obj` will result in an Exception.

Better use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or something similar unless you have a really good reason to implement your own collection classes.

Comment: Are you sure about placing spot++ and the end of the method? Nothing shows up when i do that.

Comment: No, i revised my answer. Better use List<T> if there is no need to create your own List class.